# How to convert and replace dataframe values meeting a condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a data frame in R - my_data:

```
study    value1    value2     sd_se     n
A        15           11       sd       20 
B        10           12       se       10
C        12           15       sd       25
```

I want to convert the numbers in the value1 and value2 columns from a standard error to a standard deviation if there is an "se" in the sd_se column

I imagine that this might involve something along the lines of?:

```
if (mydata$sd_se == "se"){
 apply(mydata[,c('value1', 'value2')],1,function(x) x*n^0.5)
        }
```

But am otherwise stuck. Any assistance much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `mydata[mydata$sd_se == "se", c('value1', 'value2')] <- mydata[mydata$sd_se == "se", c('value1', 'value2')] * mydata[mydata$sd_se == "se", "n"] ^ .5`

Comment: Perfect - thank you!